# More Sluggish Lagging Mouse

Tags: keyboard, mouse

Just added dual boot to my PC with a fresh Ubuntu 18.04 installation and found the mouse totally unusable but after rebooting it was fine. Today I briefly booted to Windows but when I went back to Ubuntu, it was sluggish again. After a reboot it was fine and the same wireless mouse on the same PC works fine with Windows 10.

This is an older system so no USB 3 and I tried a wired USB mouse with no change to the problem. I read everything I could find on the problem which is apparently very common so is there a once-and-for-all fix?

Some sources suggest removing and reinstalling half but that is not installed on this system. The keyboard is only slightly affected, missing the occasional keystroke and there are no other USB devices in use but when this starts happening, the mouse is too sluggish to even be usable.

Additional info: I reinstalled Ubuntu, tried different desktops and updated everything that is updatable. Still, the problem that often requires multiple hard-boots to get it going. Sometimes the mouse is sluggish on the login screen; other times it’s fine there but becomes sluggish once the desktop appears.

When sluggish, it takes several inches of physical mouse movement to move the cursor a small amount. On a second Ubuntu PC that has newer hardware, the symptoms are a bit different in that the mouse becomes jerky at times, clears itself after a while, then becomes jerky again. Clearly a bug. Two other 18.04 Ubuntu PC, each with different chipsets, also suffer similar issues.

Can anyone help?

Comment: This issue continues but no response and nothing I’ve tried, including a fresh install, has helped. The Windows partition continues to behave properly so clearly an Ubuntu issue, especially as it started several versions ago but was fine before that. I have four Ubuntu systems of different brands, chipsets and hardware but all have the identical issue.

Comment: Anything on this? I’ve tried fresh installs on four different computers but all have varying degrees of the same problem but one one of them with dual boot, the Windows partition has no problem so clearly not a fault in hardware.

Comment: Did you ever get this solved? I've just got bitten by this

Comment: No, not yet but it seems to come and go.

Comment: As an update that adds to the perplexing problem, this issue was never resolved but I noticed something odd when it is happening: my iPad's touchscreen keyboard sometimes won't take keystrokes and when it does it stutters, skips keys, types by itself and otherwise becomes virtually impossible to use! I turned off WiFi and Bluetooth as the only things that can transmit, yet the problem remains. While the PC is in a sluggish mode, I need to actually leave the room to use the iPad. It does this on all four of my Ubuntu systems (less on the laptop) so it is not limited to any one of them.