# Mouse glitching/lagging on Ubuntu Bionic

Tags: drivers, mouse

I'm using Ubuntu Bionic and a wireless battery-powered optical mouse (brand: SPLAKS). The mouse pointer on the screen lags/stutters from time to time, making the mouse difficult to use (see similar unresolved post: [More Sluggish Lagging Mouse](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1057746/more-sluggish-lagging-mouse)). I fully charged and replaced the battery recently, so I don't think it's a hardware issue. The mousepad is fairly clean, and solid black matte so that shouldn't be an issue.

Has anyone encountered this issue, and what did you do to resolve it?

Any advice from senior Ubuntu/Linux users would be appreciated. I am not too familiar with the Linux equivalent of what in Windows is called a "driver", but I am fairly bash-literate, so I would be able to implement a solution if one were provided.

Many thanks in advance.

Mike

Comment: Check out this post https://askubuntu.com/questions/1130869/keyboard-and-mouse-stuttering-on-ubuntu-18-04-with-a-new-laptop

Comment: Thank you, Shayne.